# React native, how to make a shape

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components, shapes

i'm trying to made this in react native, [image]

I tried to had a square and an oval, i tried to have border radius in a singular square, but everytime i cannot reach this result.

This is what i tried, but as i said i don't know how to reach this

```
export const StyledText = styled.Text`
  text-align: center;
  font-family: ${FONTS.fontFamily.bold};
  font-size: 29px;
  color: white;
`;

export const StyledContainer = styled.View`
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
`;

export const StyledOval = styled.View`
  width: 110%;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100-5;
  border-width: 10;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50;
  z-index: 10;
`;

export const StyledSquare = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
`;
```

Comment: use react-native-svg with transparent backeground